# IPC message passing between different process

Tags: c, linux

I tried to pass the a pointer structure using msgsnt()

```
typedef structure eventdetail
{
 long mtype;
 char name[128];
 char value[128];
}  evtDet;
```

When receiving I am not able receive value.... How can I achieve this???

Comment: From the structure declaration, I think its suppose to be `typedef struct eventdetail` or is it that `structure` is a different user defined data type?

Comment: You pass a pointer and want to receive the data? What is wrong? :-) Or is this a misunderstanding? Please correct your question, it has some typos!